# Opening DGN using Python

Tags: gdal, ogr, fiona, limitations, dgn

I'm trying to open a DGN file with Python.

I've tried with OGR:

```py
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("DGN")
file = driver.Open("C:\path_to_dgn\example.dgn")
```

which returns a `NoneType` object.

I've tried with Fiona:

```py
fiona.open("C:\path_to_dgn\example.dgn")
```

which returns this error:

> fiona.errors.DriverError: 'C:\path_to_dgn\example.dgn' not recognized
> as a supported file format.

The DGN is a Microstation v8 file, I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: try `driver=ogr.GetDriverByName("DGNv8")` instead. Find more info on https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dgnv8.html#vector-dgnv8

Comment: @Ash `driver=ogr.GetDriverByName("DGNv8")` returns `None`, doesn't look like its an OGR supported driver

Comment: Yes, it's not supported by default. The DGN driver is limited because `Microstation DGN files from Microstation versions predating version 8.0 are supported for reading`. What's your DGN version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDAL/OGR and any software that is based on it (Fiona, GeoPandas etc.) can only read DGN < v.8 by default.  From the [DGN Driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dgn.html#vector-dgn) doc:

> Microstation DGN files from Microstation versions predating version
> 8.0 are supported for reading (a DGNv8 driver, using Teigha libraries, is available to read and write DGN v8 files).

The [DGNv8 driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dgnv8.html#vector-dgnv8) is not built-in by default and is only available when GDAL has been compiled against the proprietary (non open source) Open Design Alliance Teigha library